# Facebook login popup on page load?

Tags: php, facebook

I am wondering if it is possible to automatically create a popup with the login url instead of displaying a button.

Currently I have  instead I want to have it so when the page loads (it is an iframe) it popups a window that the user logins in with and then the iframe refreshes.

I then need to get the access_token.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at this page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/javascript

you can get the access_token via javascript